# AngularJS propagate changes up through nested components

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a pattern or best practice method to propagate events or changes up through nested components in Angular 1.x?

for e.g. say we have custom components/directives in the following layout

```
<my-container>
    <main-area>
        <nav-bar></nav-bar>
        <work-area></work-area>
    </main-area>
    <side-panel></side-panel>
</my-container>
```

If the nav-bar contains buttons and some of those buttons will perform actions in the side panel then I can see two choices

1. Create a service that holds the state of the button options and inject it where it's needed
2. Use a one-way data bind that calls a function in the parent component that will alter the value in that parent.

e.g.

```
<nav-bar onButtonPress="changeValue()">
```

The changeValue() function is in the main-area's controller

I'd like to try to avoid $watches/$emits etc and keep the internal state of the components known and the scopes isolated with clearly defined inputs/outputs

Thanks!

Comment: I 'd definitely go with a service: easier to maintain and modular, plus, you keep all your scopes nice and isolated.

Answer (score 0):

`$broadcast` sends messages down through the scope(s), where as `$emit` sends messages upward through the scope(s).

Failing that you could use 2-way binding on your directives.

So you would have;

```
app.controller('MainArea', function($scope) {
    $scope.model = {};
    $scope.model.changeValue = function(){
        // do stuff in this function
    }
});

app.directive('mainArea', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: "MainArea"
    }
});

app.directive('navBar', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            model: "=ngModel"
        },
        link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
            scope.changeValue = scope.model.changeValue;
        }
    }
});
```

Then your HTML would be;

```
<main-area>
    <nav-bar ng-model="model" ng-click="changeValue">
</main-area>
```

Something like that. **I'm in a rush so it's a rough outline of the code**. The premise behind it is to basically use 2 way/1 way binding so you can pass down functionality from your parent controllers/directives.

Comment: By setting up your scope binding with model: "=ngModel", are you getting benefits from the built in ng-model directive? Or are you just using the name for consistency?

Comment: Just for consistency. You probably actually want to use one way binding. You can ready up on binding and isolated scope [here](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-sticky-notes-pt-2-isolated-scope/)